# How to Use a # in string in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Trying to create a plugin for wordpress that uses jquery:

```
echo "$('#datepicker').datepicker({ ..... ";
```

The # is working as a comment i tried `\#` to stop it but that doesnt work.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
$dispWidget = $dispWidget.'<script type="text/javascript">';
$dispWidget = $dispWidget.'$(function() {";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."$('#datepicker').datepicker({";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."changeMonth: true,";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."changeYear: true,";
```

Comment: Could you post your entire code please. Just a few lines

Comment: if it is in the middle of a `"` quote, it should not be parsed as a comment

Comment: There must be a problem elsewhere, this works fine: http://ideone.com/iTbnc

Comment: $dispWidget = $dispWidget.'<script type="text/javascript">';
$dispWidget = $dispWidget.'$(function() {";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."$('#datepicker').datepicker({";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."changeMonth: true,";
$dispWidget = $dispWidget."changeYear: true,";

Comment: triggers Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: @GeekGirl: Click the 'edit' link under the question, and post the code there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happens is this:

You open a single quote, then close it (when you juts wanted to add one to the string), and *then* add the hash, like this:

```
'..stuff..'#other stuff'
```

What you wanted was this:

```
'..stuff..\'#other stuff'
```

That single quote has to be escaped with a backslash to be treated as a character instead of a closing quote.

Comment: it gives the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, the problem was the line before it  didn't have matching quotes.

Answer (score 5):

If the error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" the problem is actually related to the dollar sign.

To fix this, use single quotes in your PHP strings and double quotes in your JavaScript.

```
echo '$("#datepicker").datepicker({ ..... ';
```

Single quotes are better for performance as well.